# How to cancel AWS 1.4.6 AmazonServiceRequest in iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an async upload process working with Amazon S3 but I am having trouble when I try to cancel it.

I'm trying to call cancel on the request but I get an unrecognised selector crash. I think this is due to the cancel method not existing in the 1.4.6 version of the AWS iOS SDK but I could be wrong, I know it definitely exists in 1.6 but unfortunately I cannot use the latest version.

[image]

[image]

Is there a different way to cancel a request in 1.4.6?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  The cancel method has been available on `AmazonServiceRequest` since version 1.4.4 as seen in [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/f9238cfc4c4da4f84e79203d5b6b8a8439a2befe/src/Amazon.Runtime/AmazonServiceRequest.m).  You may want to verify that you don't have an older version of the SDK in your Framework search path.  You can verify the version of the SDK you are using with the code metioned on [the AWS Mobile Developer Blog](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1L1QXV0CNECD2/Getting-Metadata-about-the-AWS-Mobile-SDKs&ei=hLPuUaujLMagigLhrYCgDQ&usg=AFQjCNFfMUSerLQ7ajzWL4XdkaRuDLRsJg&sig2=40rQ-g-_sRp0i0m82vJP0w&bvm=bv.49641647,d.cGE).

Can you let us know why you are unable to use the latest version of the SDK?  Is there something we can change to help make it possible for you to upgrade?